# cocos2d 2.0 App craches on device but not in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

My app craches on my device, but not in my simulator

I am using cocos2d 2.0
I have macbook air 2011 osx 10.8.2
My device is iPad 2 ios 6.0.1

It happends in b2math.h, in the line under

```
void Set(float32 x_, float32 y_) { x = x_; y = y_; }
```

It crashes on launch